# Is it possible to use CASE with IN?

Tags: t-sql, parameters, case

I'm trying to construct a T-SQL statement with a `WHERE` clause determined by an input parameter. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN
CASE WHEN @param THEN
(1,2,4,5,8)
ELSE
(9,7,3)
END
```

I've tried all combination of moving the IN, CASE etc around that I can think of. Is this (or something like it) possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (@param='??' AND id IN (1,2,4,5,8))
OR (@param!='??' AND id in (9,7,3))
```

this will have a problem using an index.

The key with a dynamic search conditions is to make sure an index is used, instead of how can I easily reuse code, eliminate duplications in a query, or try to do everything with the same query. Here is a very comprehensive article on how to handle this topic:

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)

It covers all the issues and methods of trying to write queries with multiple optional search conditions.  This main thing you need to be concerned with is not the duplication of code, but the use of an index.  If your query fails to use an index, it will preform poorly.  There are several techniques that can be used, which may or may not allow an index to be used.

here is the table of contents:

```
  Introduction
      The Case Study: Searching Orders
      The Northgale Database
   Dynamic SQL
      Introduction
      Using sp_executesql
      Using the CLR
      Using EXEC()
      When Caching Is Not Really What You Want
   Static SQL
      Introduction
      x = @x OR @x IS NULL
      Using IF statements
      Umachandar's Bag of Tricks
      Using Temp Tables
      x = @x AND @x IS NOT NULL
      Handling Complex Conditions
   Hybrid Solutions – Using both Static and Dynamic SQL
      Using Views
      Using Inline Table Functions
   Conclusion
   Feedback and Acknowledgements
   Revision History
```

if you are on the proper version of SQL Server 2008, there is an additional technique that can be used, see: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL Version for SQL 2008 (SP1 CU5 and later)](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

If you are on that proper release of SQL Server 2008, you can just add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query and the local variable's value at run time is used for the optimizations.

Consider this, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` will take this code (where no index can be used with this mess of `OR`s):

```
WHERE
    (@search1 IS NULL or Column1=@Search1)
    AND (@search2 IS NULL or Column2=@Search2)
    AND (@search3 IS NULL or Column3=@Search3)
```

and optimize it at run time to be (provided that only @Search2 was passed in with a value):

```
WHERE
    Column2=@Search2
```

and an index can be used (if you have one defined on Column2)

Answer (score 0):

```
if @param = 'whatever'
   select * from tbl where id in (1,2,4,5,8)
else
   select * from tbl where id in (9,7,3)
```